# Plugin cakephp 3.7

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-3.7

How can I map a plugin  into the cakephp 3.7, through a remote folder?

after version 3.4 I am no longer able to load a plugin, I looked at the documentation and checked that it had changes already tried using Application :: addplugin (); and Application :: bootstrap (); that were the solutions I found searching, I do not know if I have to do any more procedure or if some other syntax has changed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**From CakePHP documentation:**

> The plugin shell allows you to load and unload plugins via the command
>   prompt. If you need help, run:

```
bin/cake plugin --help
```

> **Loading Plugins**
>
> Via the Load task you are able to load plugins in your
>   config/bootstrap.php. You can do this by running:

```
bin/cake plugin load MyPlugin
```

> This will add the following to your src/Application.php:

```
// In the bootstrap method add:
$this->addPlugin('MyPlugin');

// Prior to 3.6, add the following to config/bootstrap.php
Plugin::load('MyPlugin');
```

If you need plugin before any method / event in your bootstrap, then use like:

```
class Application extends BaseApplication
    {
        /**
         * {@inheritDoc}
         */
        public function bootstrap()
        {
            $this->addPlugin('OAuthServer', ['routes' => true]);

            // Call parent to load bootstrap from files.
            parent::bootstrap();

            if (PHP_SAPI === 'cli') {
                try {
                    $this->addPlugin('Bake');
                } catch (MissingPluginException $e) {
                    // Do not halt if the plugin is missing
                }

                $this->addPlugin('Migrations');
            }

            /*
             * Only try to load DebugKit in development mode
             * Debug Kit should not be installed on a production system
             */
            if (Configure::read('debug')) {
                $this->addPlugin(\DebugKit\Plugin::class);
            }

            // Other plugins
            $this->addPlugin('BootstrapUI');
            $this->addPlugin('Search');
```

**Read more:**

https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/console-and-shells/plugin-shell.html